# homotopy invariance for singular homology for maps of pairs

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let R be a ring, $(X,A), (Y,B)$ pairs of topological spaces and $f,g:(X,A)\to (Y,B)$ continuous maps of pairs such that there exists $H:X\times I\to Y$ homotopy with $H(A\times I)\subseteq B$, $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$. The claim is: 
$(f,f_{|A})_*=(g,g_{|A})_*:H_n(X,A)\to H_n(Y,B)$. (we consider singular homology with coefficients in R) 
I dont see the difficulty and i dont see the problem/what to prove.
I know the homotopy invariance for singular homology for homotopic maps $u,v:X\to Y$. And $f,g:X\to Y$ are homotopic, therefore $H_n(f)=H_n(g)$. 
But  i would say that $f_{|A}, g_{|A}$ must be homotopic if you consider H restrict on A. But it can't be enough. Could you help me how to prove it?  Regards

Comment: Regardless of my previous unsuccessful attempt, this is proposition 2.19 in Hatcher's book *Algebraic Topology*, if you want to check it out.

Comment: hi. thank you. i wanted to try it with the commutative diagramm as you had proposed it because that was my idea to try this too. but you mean it isn't successful and you have deleted your answer is it correct?

Comment: Yes, what I wrote earlier doesn't work. It might be possible to tweak it using some sort of mapping cylinders, but I'm not sure.

Comment: and thank you for the hint. maybe if nothing of my ideas work i will take a look in hatcher